# Copying formula and formating using macros

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the formula and formatting prepopulated in the next row where data in present. 
I have tried the following

```
Sub CopyMacro()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ActiveSheet.Range(Range("F").End(xlUp), "G" & Range("F").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("F").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyMacro()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Offset(0, 4).Resize(, 2).AutoFill Destination:=.Offset(0, 4).Resize(2, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! I had a question though if I want to make it worksheet (say Sheet2) specific than what do I need to change. I'm thinking it will be better to make it worksheet specific. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: `I'm thinking it will be better to make it worksheet specific` - absolutelly true! See my updated answer:)

Comment: thanks that is perfect! Can you please explain the  Offset(1,0) & Offset(0,4) sections.

Comment: sure, __1)__ `.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` gives you last non empty cell in column `B`, say `B12`. __2)__ `Offset(1,0)` means get cell one row below from `B12`, i.e. `B13`. __3)__ `Offset(0,4)` gives you cell 4 columns to the right from `B12`, i.e. `F12` __4)__ and finally `.Resize(, 2)` "stretch" `F12` to two-column range, i.e. `F12:G12`

Comment: had a quick question for you. If my Sheet 2 is a table then this code does not work. Can you please let me know why?

Comment: Table has it's own nature. It doesn't behave as ordinary excel cells. There should be completly different approach (you should add new row in `ListObject` object in VBA rather just copy formats and formulas). Since it's far from original question, it would be better to post new question (it's hard to answer on it in comments)